# Getting Error from Adding and Printing Linked Lists

Tags: java, linked-list

Briefly, I want my code to add the given elements to the list and print it to the screen. The Problem is, it prints the last element of the list for 3 times and doesn't print the others. I spent so much time but I couldn't find the problem.

```
public class Book {

private String name;
private double price;
private String writer;

public Book(String name, double price, String writer) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.writer = writer;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public String getWriter() {
    return writer;
}
public void setWriter(String writer) {
    this.writer = writer;
}
}
```

Here is the Node class:

```
public class Node {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Node nd = new Node(bk);
    Book bk1;
    bk1 = new Book("Of Mice and Men", 22, "John Steinbeck");
    nd.add(bk1);

    bk1 = new Book("The Grapes of Wrath", 28, "John Steinbeck");
    nd.add(bk1);

    bk1 = new Book("Tortilla Flat", 33, "John Steinbeck");
    nd.add(bk1);

    nd.printData();

}

private static Book bk;
private Node link;
public Node root;


public Book getBk() {
    return bk;
}
public void setBk(Book bk) {
    this.bk = bk;
}
public Node getLink() {
    return link;
}
public void setMyNode(Node link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public Node(Book bk) {
    super();
    this.bk = bk;
    this.link=null;
    this.root=null;

}

public void add(Book bk) {
    Node currentNode = root;
    Node newNode = new Node(bk);
    if(root==null){

        root = newNode;
    }
    else{
    while(currentNode.link!=null){

        currentNode = currentNode.link;

    }
    currentNode.link = newNode;
}
}

public void printData() {
    Node currentNode = root;

    while(currentNode!=null){
        Book bk = currentNode.getBk();
        System.out.println("Name: " + bk.getName() + " Price: " + bk.getPrice() + " Writer: " + bk.getWriter());
        currentNode =currentNode.link;
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Could you format your code? highlight your code and press Ctrl + K, it makes it easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: what is the value of bk here in node class? `Node nd = new Node(bk);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Node Class also needs a Book instance variable:

```
private static Book bk;
private Book book;
private Node link;
public Node root;
```

Then these methods need updated to use the instance variable over the class variable:

```
public Book getBk() {
    return book;
}
public void setBk(Book bk) {
    this.book = bk;
}
public Node(Book bk) {
    super();
    this.book = bk;
    this.link=null;
    this.root=null;

}
```

I have tested this and it works.

Hope this helps,

Liam

Answer (score 0):

Use three different Books instead of only one `bk1`.